# How to move GUI windows in CDE via command line without additional software (i.e. no wmctrl,xdotool, etc)

Tags: perl, solaris, x11

I work on a system that is using Solaris/CDE and have to manipulate the location of many windows manually hundreds of times a day.  I'd like to automate this process via a shell or perl script.

I've done tons of research so far and found that most people can use wmctrl or xdotool to solve this problem.  I have no admin rights in order to install these packages.  I also lack a java/c compiler. I do however have access to perl (of which I'm fairly fluent in) or can write command line scripts.

I don't need anything as fully featured as wmctrl or xdotool, I only need to move the windows.  I've been able to get the details of my GUIs via xprop but am unsure on where to go from here.   Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you need admin rights to install those?

Comment: The system is on a company intranet and I don't have any ability to transfer files/code over to the system.  Its a silly policy especially since they'll let us write all the perl scripts we could want.

Comment: For GUIs you are probably out of luck.  Terminal windows in CDE would be `dtterm`, which do respond to escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for [`xprop`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xprop.1.html) indicates that it is capable of setting property values:

> **-set property-name** *value*
>
> Specifies the *name* of a property and a property *value*, to be set on the indicated window.

No sample script was given to show the way OP is using `xprop` to retrieve values, but the output of `xprop` is easily parsed.  Here is an example:

```
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
            window state: Normal
            icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1942
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x600023
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xterm-319", "UXTerm"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
            Client accepts input or input focus: True
            Initial state is Normal State.
            bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x600030
            bitmap id # of mask for icon: 0x600032
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
            program specified size: 804 by 804
            program specified minimum size: 16 by 51
            program specified resize increment: 10 by 20
            program specified base size: 6 by 31
            window gravity: NorthWest
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "michener.jexium-island.net"
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "xterm-319", "-class", "UXTerm", "-title", "uxterm", "-u8" }
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "[unnamed] - vile"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "[unnamed] - vile"
```

As for how to proceed: if I were developing a script like that, I would have a function to parse that output into name/value pairs, and have an option for updating one of the window properties—referring to the source code of [`wmctrl`](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/) and [`xprop`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xprop) to see how the properties should be formatted.  The documentation for [`WM_SIZE_HINTS`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-normal-hints.html) is required to make sense of *that*.